# How to import CLaML into MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've tried `LOAD XML` [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html) but it's not working.

Here is [the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2h7t8aZbPbiVDNZSEJybEFvQlE/view?usp=sharing) I need to import.

Comment: show us how do you have tried to import the xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an appropriate parser on [github](https://github.com/ultrah/ClaMLParser/).

More comprehensive concept can be found on [protege project](http://protege.stanford.edu/) of Stanford